# How can the below graph be interpreted

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, heteroscedasticity

[image]

How can you interpret the scale location graph in terms of Homoscedasticity?

Answer (score 1):

If one were to take the downward slope of the red line seriously, this would imply that as the predicted value of Salary increases, the typical difference between the prediction and the observed value decreases. This would imply a lack of homoscedasticity.

If you want to know whether heteroscedasticity is present in your population, you could run a test to figure that out. I can say by looking at this graph that pretty much any test would give a nonsignificant result. That doesn't mean homoscedasticity holds; it just means that if heteroscedasticity is present, you could not detect it in your sample.

If you're worried about heteroscedasticity affecting the validity of your inference from the model, you can use a heteroscedastic-consistent standard error. An easy way to access this is through the `lm_robust` function in the `estimatr` package. If heteroscedasticity is of substantive interest, then you could try modeling it and figuring out why it might be present (though in this sample you would be unlikely to find anything due to the sample size and small apparent magnitude of the phenomenon).